# how to make Firstname selected from both Firstname and Lastname in display (Label key) Typeahead React

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, typeahead.js, autosuggest, bootstrap-typeahead

How to select the first name only (i.e selected should be Firstname), when both first name and last name is in display (Label key ) in type ahead react.

```
     <Typeahead
    id="typeahead"
      labelKey={option => `${option.firstName} ${option.lastName}`}
      options={[
      { id: 1, firstName: "Art", lastName: "Blakey" },
      { id: 2, firstName: "John", lastName: "Coltrane" },
      { id: 3, firstName: "Miles", lastName: "Davis" },
      { id: 4, firstName: "Herbie", lastName: "Hancock" },
      { id: 5, firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Parker" },
      { id: 6, firstName: "Tony", lastName: "Williams" }
    ]}
    placeholder="Selected Value must be FirstName"

  />
```

Comment: Can you just modify labelKey={option => `${option.firstName}`} ?

Comment: you can jus add labelkey="firstName"